# Wifi not detected Xubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless, 13.10, xubuntu

I'm running Xubuntu 13.10 on a Compaq Presario V2000 with a BRCM 4318 wireless card. When I turn it on Xubuntu doesn't attempt to search for wireless networks, instead saying the ethernet is offline. I have installed b43-fwcutter and the drivers from the install media. What can I do to make Xubuntu attempt to connect?

Comment: Let's just verify your device. Please edit your question to add the results of these terminal commands: lspci -nn | grep 0280 and also: lsmod | grep -e wl-e b43

Comment: `steve@steve-Presario-V2000-EX657UA-ABA:~$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
05:02.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4318] (rev 02)  
steve@steve-Presario-V2000-EX657UA-ABA:~$ lsmod | grep -e wl-e b43
grep: b43: No such file or directory`                       Also worth noting I have no "enable wifi" option in the network indicator.

Comment: Sorry for my typo. I meant: lsmod | grep -e wl -e b43

Comment: `steve@steve-Presario-V2000-EX657UA-ABA:~$ lsmod | grep -e wl -e b43
wl   
                
4161817  1 lib80211  
             
14040  1 wlcfg80211 
             
401436  1 wl`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please get a temporary wired ethernet connect, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Detach the ethernet, reboot and tell us if it's working.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working.

Comment: Now the package is called `firmware-b43-installer` instead of `linux-firmware-nonfree`.