# wifi is not coming up in network connections in xubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, drivers, xubuntu, 15.04

I have no problem with wired connection, but wifi is not even an option on my newly installed xubuntu 15.04. I found similar question (Wifi not detected Xubuntu 13.10) and run the commands in terminal, here is the output:

```
op@op:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
06:02.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4318] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Broadcom 802.11b/g WLAN [103c:1355]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
op@op:~$ lsmod | grep -e wl -e b43
wl                   6152192  1 
cfg80211              462848  1 wl
```

This is what I have after running it again:

```
op@op:~$ lsmod | grep -e wl -e b43
b43                   401408  0 
bcma                   49152  1 b43
mac80211              626688  1 b43
cfg80211              462848  2 b43,mac80211
ssb                    57344  1 b43

op@op:~$ sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
[sudo] password for op: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'bcmwl-kernel-source' is not installed, so not removed

op@op:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-firmware-nonfree is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dkms linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic thermald
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.

No files to remove, no files to install and still no wifi.
```

Any ideas???

Here is what I tried and collected as much info as I could. Please look:
Uninstalled all wifi drivers from the system:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo app-get autoremove
```

Restart.
Restart hangs forever. Power Down. PC comes back up with “System program problem detected”
Installing linux-firmware-nonfree

`sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`
Looks good so far:

```
Preparing to unpack .../linux-firmware-nonfree_1.16_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-firmware-nonfree (1.16) ...
Setting up linux-firmware-nonfree (1.16) ...
op@op:~$
```

Unplug Ethernet cable and restart.
no wifi please see screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KF9Vd.jpg
Plug Ethernet cable back
removing linux-firmware-nonfree
installing bcmwl-kernel-source and it hangs after installing no prompt available system is workable just terminal hanging. Please see bellow:
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.248+bdcom DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.19.0-28-generic
Building for architecture i686
Building initial module for 3.19.0-28-generic
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.19.0-28-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.

NO PROMPT!
RESTARTING. Hangs on the Xubuntu logo, Doesn’t restart.
Power down. Comes back same story. No wifi.
Since this was not an issue in Xubuntu 14 should I downgrade?

Comment: Just run the commands. The worst that can happen is you'll lose your WiFi connectivity, which you don't have. Can you edit in a direct link to the question you're referring to?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/394521/wifi-not-detected-xubuntu-13-10

Comment: Do the commands in the answer. I can confirm these work on 14.04.

Comment: Did not help, I opened Software & Updates here is what it shows:

Comment: You need to reboot afterwards. Did you do that?

Comment: Did not help, I opened Software & Updates here is what it shows: well how do I attach the screen shot? Yes I did reboot. anyway it shows that this device is not working. do not use.

Comment: Upload it to Imgur and link it in your question.

Comment: Here is the link to the image: http://imgur.com/fUIKa9J when I said I reboot it, it actually was not true. the laptop was trying to reboot for 3 min. the xubuntu logo was going and going. I powered it down.

Comment: Select the other option there. It's a choice whether or not to use the device. There pretty bad phrasing on the option, so I can see where confusion might be an issue.

Comment: When I changed it to the driver, just before finishing installing  it, It froze the system for more than 10 min and I shut it down. When it came back there was no driver to choose in the software updater it is disappeared.

Comment: Does your WiFi work though?

Comment: No I still do not have wifi
This is the image of my wifi button which used to glow with windows xp
http://imgur.com/JGLDbV4,UAnpxN6,y0A4OPd

This is the image when my system froze during installation
http://imgur.com/JGLDbV4,UAnpxN6,y0A4OPd#1

This is image of problems detected when I shut down my laptop and boot it buck up. Same 20 minutes ago when I started my laptop for the first time today. 
http://imgur.com/JGLDbV4,UAnpxN6,y0A4OPd#2

What should I do. Please help.
Should I re install the  generic free driver?
Should I re install xubuntu?
If yes please let me know how.

Comment: Try the commands in the answer to the other question again. You'll need to hook up to the internet using a wired connection.

Comment: Still nothing. I did edit my question with new information if you can look please.

Comment: Swap the commands and reboot.

Comment: install first then remove?

Comment: No. Install what you were trying to remove and remove what you were trying to install.

Comment: As you said I removed linux-firware-free and instaling bcmwl-kernel
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu2) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.248+bdcom DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.19.0-28-generic
Building for architecture i686
Building initial module for 3.19.0-28-generic
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.19.0-28-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
no prompt, what do I do?

Comment: Maybe try rebooting

Comment: Hi Zacharee1, restart did not work, had to power down. Edited my question, added more info from terminal and screenshots. Should I down grade to 14 maybe?

Comment: You could try that

Comment: Thank you Zacharee1 for sticking with me for so many days :)) Though problem was solved with the other suggestions I've learned a lot from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried everything but the correct command. To install firmware for your adapter you need to purge `bcmwl-kernel-source` and run

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Comment: This is awesome!!! Thank you, Thank you, Thank you Pilot6! Wireless works now! I was truly looking through the questions for similarity but did not see the one you suggested as duplicate. I'm using Linux only for 2 months so it is all new for me. What do I do with my question since it is duplicate? Delete it? Sorry it doesn't let me to do the vote for you since I have less then 15 reputations (what ever it is :))

Comment: @pripe You are welcome. Just leave the question as it is. It wall show the way to other people with similar problems.